# How can I define a Currency-per-Kg number format using i18n?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internationalization, i18next, vue-i18n

I am using the vue i18n plugin for a project and we have defined our own number formats for example:

```
kgPerHa: {   
  style: "unit",
  unit: "kilogram-per-hectare",
  maximumFractionDigits: 3,
}
```

and this works fine when using the kgPerHa in vue. Now i need to define a format like currency-per-kg (specifically euro/kg).
one of the many curent attempts

```
EuroPerKg: {
  style: "currency-per-unit",
  unit: "EUR-per-kilogram"
}
```

it won't work out of the box and the i18n Documentation is not helping at all.